# Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: c++, xcode, class

```
class Card
{
private:
  int face;
  char suit;
public:
  Card();
  Card(char, int);
  int getRank() { return face; }
  char getSuit() { return suit; }
  void setFace(int cardFace) { face = cardFace; }
  void setSuit(char cardSuit) { suit = cardSuit; }
};
Card::Card(char cardSuit, int cardFace)
{
  face = cardFace;
  suit = cardSuit;
}

class Player
{  
public:
  Player();
  vector<Card>allCards;
  vector<Card>hand;   //holds 7 cards
};

Player::Player()
{
  std::random_device seed;
  std::mt19937 rng(seed());
  for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
  {
      Card c1('D', i), c2('C', i), c3('H', i), c4('S', i);
      allCards.push_back(c1);
      allCards.push_back(c2);
      allCards.push_back(c3);
      allCards.push_back(c4);
  }
  shuffle(std::begin(allCards), std::end(allCards), rng);
      for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
          hand[x] = allCards.back(); <---------- Error here
          allCards.pop_back();
      }
}
```

I am trying to create a game using classes and at some moment I have to assign 7 cards to each player, which is not working for me the way I'm trying to manage it.

I receive the following error

```
Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

Comment: I dont see vector<Card>allCards being initialized in the code. Try after initializing the vector.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf please look at the code again. 52 elements are pushed to 'allCards' before popping 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the `hand` vector. By default it has a size of `0` and accessing `hand[x]` is out of bounds.

If you know it will have a constant size you can initialize its size in the initialization list of the `Player` constructor.

```
Player::Player() : hand(HAND_SIZE) {
   ...
}
```

or you can change your code to use `push_back()` since `hand` is empty unless initialized otherwise.

```
hand.push_back(allCards.back());
```